# What does this mean? いや　しつこに鞄いらんにろ

Tags: meaning

[image: picture of sentence]

> いや　しつこに鞄いらんにろ

I am having trouble with it. Why is に behind しつこ? Is it saying the bag is persistent? What does the sentence mean?

Comment: Notice that the つ there is small -- that isn't [しつこ]{shitsuko}, that is [しっこ]{shikko}.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a small っ to me, so the word would be しっこ meaning 'pee' (as in urine): https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93. Nothing to do with しつこい. It's hard to tell without any context but would "you don't need a bag to pee/for pee" make any more sense? If you're still having a hard time understanding, it would be useful to see a bit more of the context if you can provide a link (I'm quite curious to see too now).

Comment: Ohhh yes that makes more sense! Thank you so much!